# Lumen + doctrine : Auth guard [] is not defined

Tags: laravel, doctrine, lumen

I am creating first Lumen + Doctrine Application. and i have Authintication problem. here is my Authenticate.php middleware:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

but it gives me the error

> (1/1) InvalidArgumentException
>   Auth guard [] is not defined.

Comment: What version of Lumen are you using?

Comment: lumne 5.8, and doctrine 1.0.*